# A new characterization of Riemann-Integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration

- **Question :**

Given two bounded functions $\,f:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}\,$
and $\;θ:(0,b−a]→[0,1]$.

Suppose $\,P:a=x_0<x_1<⋯<x_n=b\;$ is a partition of $\,[a,b]$.

Let $\,Δx_k=x_k−x_{k−1}\,$ and $\,\Vert{P}\Vert=\max\limits_{1≤k≤n}Δx_k$.

If
$$∃\,A∈\mathbb{R},\,∀ϵ>0,\,∃δ>0:\,∀P\,(\Vert{P}\Vert<δ)⟹\Biggl\vert\sum_{k=1}^n f\bigl(x_{k−1}+θ(Δx_k)Δx_k\bigr)Δx_k−A\Biggr\vert<ϵ\,,$$

i.e.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n f\bigl(x_{k−1}+θ(Δx_k)Δx_k\bigr)Δx_k\,\longrightarrow A\;(\Vert{P}\Vert→0)\,,$$

then can we always conclude that $\,f\,$ is Riemann-integrable?

---

- **Background :**

I notice that Kristensen, Poulsen and Reich (A characterization of Riemann-Integrability, The American Mathematical Monthly, vol.69, No.6, pp. 498-505) have proved a similar result with the Darboux property, but my question need not satisfy Darboux property.

Can anybody help me? Any hints or solution would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!